# How can I initialize a for loop inside ScrollView with Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, kivy-language

I am new to `Kivy` and I am trying to figure out how to use `ScrollView`. I am wondering how I can initialize buttons generated inside `for` loop inside `ScrollView`. Here is my code so far:

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class My_list(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        for i in range(10):
            b = Button(text=str(i))
            self.add_widget(b)

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

## my.kv

```
MyBoxLayout:

<MyBoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"

#    ScrollView:
#        size_hint: 1, None
#        height: 200

    My_list:

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        TextInput:
        TextInput:

    Button:
        text: "Add Button"
        size_hint: 1, .1
```

This looks how I want it, but I want to move number buttons with scrollbar if there are too many to be shown on screen. Scrollbar should not affect input widgets and `Add Button`.

I tried this in `my.kv`:

```
ScrollView:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: 200

    My_list:
```

But it seems to mess up the whole layout. Is there a way to use the for loop inside `.kv` file? Or is what other way is to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Kivy documentation,

> You must carefully specify the size of your content to get the desired scroll/pan effect.
> By default, the size_hint is (1, 1), so the content size will fit your ScrollView exactly (you will have nothing to scroll). You must deactivate at least one of the size_hint instructions (x or y) of the child to enable scrolling. Setting size_hint_min to not be None will also enable scrolling for that dimension when the ScrollView is smaller than the minimum size.

So the changes you need, in `my.kv`,

```py
    ScrollView:
#        size_hint: 1, None # Generally you don't need this.
#        height: 200 # Neither this.
        
        My_list:
            size_hint_y: None # Let the container expand vertically.
            height: self.minimum_height # Or, you can specify any other value.
```

And in `My_list`,

```py
        b = Button(
                text=str(i),
                size_hint_y = None, # To set custom value.
                height = dp(100), # Specify height of the widget explicitly.
            )
        self.add_widget(b)
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Adding to your answer `from kivy.metrics import dp`is also needed in `mein.py`.

Comment: That's quite obvious. However, there are some advantages of using `dp` over normal values, it will always render (automatically) the expected size no matter what the the device's pixel values (resolution) are. Additionally, `sp` does the same job for label's font size unless you want a standardized value in which case you can use `pt`.